# Recruitment involving Veil of Shadows

Tags: werewolv.es

As a sort of follow up question to a previous question regarding the Veil, how would recruitment work?

For example:

A) An inquisition leader recruiting a village WC holding the Veil

B) Any town recruiter trying to recruit an evil role holding the Veil (Does it differ if trying to recruit a wolf or vamp that would normally kill the recruiter?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game resolves these interactions by checking directly against the player's **true role**, not at the player's *observed* alignment/killer status/witchcraft status, as intel-gathering roles do.

This means that a recruitment attempt by Inquisition Leader on a Seer with a Veil of Shadows would still bounce, and an attempt against a Vampire with a Veil would still result in death for the Leader.